# How to change the size of transparent background in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, images, transparency, resize

The following image cuts when used as a logo [here](http://arcube.sandbox.fedena.com/). I want to increase the size of the transparent background so it fits in properly without the underneath cut, as shown [here](http://demo.arcube.com.ng). Using Gimp 2.8, how can I accomplish this?

[image: Cut Image] [image]

Any help is apprecited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want Fit canvas to layers: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-resize-to-layers.html

And it could be that you didn't know about the difference between the canvas - the visible area of the image, and layers - the parts that the image content consists of.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed [it](http://arcube.sandbox.fedena.com/) after playing around in Gimp for a bit.

1. Open the image in Gimp.
2. Press "R" or "CTRL + A" to select your image.
3. Right click on the image, select: FX-Foundry -> Image Effects -> "**Resize Image to Layers...**".
4. Enter a numeric value for: Border Size (Pixels), I used `45`.
5. Select "OK" to apply the changes and press CTRL + E to export the image.

[image]

I hope this helps! :)